# Creating a invoiceline class

Tags: java

Invoice Line class represent some line in the invoice that records the item sold and the quantity.An invoice line should include the following attributes: item Sold: this is an instance variable of type Item.
quantity: an integer that represents the number of units being purchased of this item.Include the following methods in your Invoice Line class: A constructor that takes the following four input parameters: item number, item description, item price, and quantity. The constructor then uses the input parameters to initialize the two instance variables to getters and setters methods for the two instance variable so get Line Total: a method to calculate and return the total price for this line (i.e., quantity * item’s price). to String method that returns a one-line description of the invoice line. The description should include item’s details, quantity purchased, and total cost of the line.

*** I am trying to get the other variables from a different class called item class to the invoiceline class, but I cannot seem to do it. So far I have this. Any Help!?

```
public class InvoiceLine {
//Instance Variables
private Item itemSold;
private int quantity;

// Constructors
public InvoiceLine(){}

public InvoiceLine(String itemSold, int quantity){
    itemSold = new Item(itemSold);
    this.quantity = quantity;   
}
//Getters 
public Item getItemSold(){
    return itemSold;
}
public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}
//Setters
private void setItemSold(Item itemSold){
    this.itemSold = itemSold;
}
private void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
// Methods
public double getLineTotal(double total){
    total = itemPrice * quantity;
    return total;
}
public String toString(){
    String invoiceLine = "";
    invoiceLine = (itemSold + " brought "+ quantity + ", which the total cost is "+ total);
    return invoiceLine;
}
```

}

Item Class:

```
public class Item {
//Instance Variables
private int itemNum;
private String itemDescription;
private double itemPrice;

//Constructors
public Item(){}

//Initialize the three variables
public Item(int itemN, String itemDesc, double itemPri){
    this.itemNum = itemN;
    this.itemDescription = itemDesc;
    this.itemPrice = itemPri;
}
public Item(String itemDesc){
    this.itemDescription = itemDesc;
    this.itemNum = 0;
    this.itemPrice = 0;
}
//Getters
public int getItemNum(){
    return itemNum;
}
public String getItemDescription(){
    return itemDescription;
}
public double getItemPrice(){
    return itemPrice;
}
//Setters
private void setItemNum(int itemN){
    itemNum = itemN;
}
private void setItemDescription(String itemDesc){
    itemDescription = itemDesc;
}
private void setItemPrice(double itemPri){
    itemPrice = itemPri;
}
// toString method output description of the item
public String toString(){
    String itemDetail = "";
    itemDetail = ("Item number is "+ itemNum + ", which is a "+ itemDescription + " and price is " + itemPrice);
    return itemDetail;
}
```

}

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem you have?

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot get the item class variable itemPrice to multiply quantity. I don't know if I call it or not.

Comment: Maybe `itemSold.getItemPrice()`?

Comment: I think we suppose to use the class name

Comment: I don't know which methods your Item class has. But you should be able to use a getter on your itemSold object that you initialize in your constructor...

Comment: Maybe post your Item class also so I can see exactly how you should call it

Comment: This.... Is not... What?? Do you understand what you are writing?

Comment: Please try to demonstrate exactly where is the problem. Do you get an error? Post the error and exactly where you get it...

Comment: I do. Its just I'm not able to get the itemPrice from my Item class to my Invoiceline class.

Comment: I will ask this one last time. Post the exact error you get and the line where you get it. Otherwise I can't help you. Sorry good luck

Comment: It says constructor Item(Item) is undefined. itemSold = new Item(itemSold);. Other than that everything is fine. So I think the problem has to do with what I am calling the Item class.

Comment: Well then you need to define the appropriate constructor in your Item class, one that accepts a String... That's your issue....not difficult

Comment: Also it's a bad idea to use `itemSold' as a parameter for the constructor and an instance variable, choose different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `itemSold = new Item(itemSold);` to `this.itemSold = new Item(itemSold);`
In this case the parameter itemSold is shadowing the attribute itemSold, so to access the attribute you have to prefix it with `this`.

Comment: Yeah, I change it to that and I made it work already except the calculations of the quantity and the price doesn't work. It says operator * is underfined for agrument type Item, [int. total = itemSold * quantity;]

Comment: You need to get the price from the itemSold. Like this: `itemSold.getItemPrice()` because itemSold is an Object and you can't multiply an Object with a double

Comment: It doesn't work. For example, public itemSold.getItemPrice(){
  return itemPrice;
 }

Comment: Don't put the code of the function where you're calling it! The getter getItemPrice is defined in Item and you call it in your other function getLineTotal. When you call a function you don't specify the code that it is executing. So just leave out the {..} when you're calling getItemPrice, but don't edit the definition of getItemPrice in Item.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it already. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: total = (quantity * itemSold.getItemPrice()); Like This!

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer ;)